# How to get selected value from DataGridHyperlinkColumn using wpf data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My data grid have one DataGridHyperlinkColumn , but on click of that hyper link I am not getting the value . my data grid is,

```
<datagrid name="datagrid1">
   <column>
      <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID"  Width="100" >
         <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" >
               <EventSetter  Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="Hyperlink_Click"  />
            </Style>
         </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
      </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
   </column>
</datagrid>
```

how I will get the Id in  Hyperlink_Click method.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Tag property of the Hyperlink with ID and get the Tag value like this

```
 private void  Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            HyperlinkButton hlb = (HyperlinkButton)sender;
            if(hlb !=null){
               var id = hlb.tag
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the `ID` from `TextBlock`'s `DataContext` like so :

```
private void Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //cast sender to TextBlock, and get it's data context
    var dc = ((TextBlock)sender).DataContext;
    //cast data context to your model type, and get the ID property
    var id = ((YourModelType)dc).ID;
}
```

Or you can set `Tag` property of the `TextBlock` like suggested in the other answer :

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID"  Width="100" >
    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" >
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding ID}" />
            <EventSetter  Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="Hyperlink_Click"  />
        </Style>
    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

Then you can get `ID` value in the event handler like this :

```
private void Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock textblock = (TextBlock)sender;
    string id = (string)textblock.Tag;
}
```